# How do I get the dimensions of the view (not obstructed by scrollbars) in a wx.ScrolledWindow?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, scrolledwindow

Is there an easy way to do this?  Alternatively, if I could get the width of the scrollbars, I could just use the dimensions of the ScrolledWindow and subtract them out myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric() with wx.SYS_HSCROLL_Y and wx.SYS_VSCROLL_X to get the scrollbar sizes.  Then use window.GetClientSize() and subtract it out.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxsystemsettings.html#wxsystemsettings

```
>>> wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_HSCROLL_Y)
16
>>> wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric(wx.SYS_VSCROLL_X)
16
```